# Ways to store the data permanently

Tags: java, sql, database

I've been trying to make a Vault which stores the passwords and username of a user. But to accomplish this task there is a need for me to store the data permanently so that it should be stored in computer after it is restarted.
I searched it on google and found that we can store data **permanently** using database and using a *.txt* or *.bin* file.
I do not want to go with *.txt* method (as data can be altered easily) but want to go with database method.
So my question is:-
"Is there a way to store the data in a SQL database?"
If yes then how?

---

Please help me!!!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes there is , take a look [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement)

Comment: If you want to store it locally on the computer, what do you need a database for ? Do you think the user edits his/her own login details ? If you still think so, consider an encryption algorithm too. Storing data in a `.txt` file or in any other extension does not make data unsafe. You can edit every file. What the file CONTAINS matters. Not the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check mysql DB - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/

And JDBC connection for connecting to mysql from Java - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm